# Zend Framework: Rename upload file

Tags: zend-framework

I have problem with rename file. I need new file name be cyrillic but, when rename img in img folder new name is "РҐСЂРёСЃС‚Рѕ Р‘РѕС‚РµРІ.jpg". That is my code:

```
 $newName = $formdata['name'];

 try {
       $ext = end(explode('.', $form->img3->getFileName()));
       path = (APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/imgs/' . $newName . '.') . $ext;

       $form->img3->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => $path,
                        'overwrite' => true));

       $form->img3->receive();

       $form->reset();
    } 
       catch (Exception $e) 
       {
         $editMessage[][] = 'Invalid image.';
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$path = (APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/imgs/' . $newName . '.') . $ext;
$path = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1251', $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using iconv() function to convert the encoding of the file name.

[More info about iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)